# String can't be extended via 'PLUS'

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a simple question. Please have a look at following script:

```
def myFunc(string):
    res=''
    for i in string:
        if not i in res:
            res+i
    return res
res=myFunc('aaaa')
print(res)               # return a string 'a'
```

This script should be able to delete the repeated char in the input string.

Actually, however, I got nothing. The 'res' is NULL.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You should assign the res value. res = res + i, otherwise you are adding the value but not storing it back.

Answer (score 0):

`res+i` is not setting its result to a variable. You need to add this back to the string..

```
res = res + i
```

Comment: is this because i can't change the string at the original place? So i have to assign it  to a new name? It is not like list.append(), right?

Comment: @Harry - Strings are immutable, but its more about how the `+` operator works. In most cases, it is not intended to modify the left hand operator

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't make an assignement. Check my code where I do `res = res+i`.

```
def myFunc(string):
    res=''
    for i in string:
        if not i in res:
            res = res+i
    return res

res=myFunc('aaaa')
print(res)               # return a string 'a'
```

Comment: thanks! is this because i can't change the string at the original place? So i have to assign it to a new name? It is not like list.append(), right?

Comment: append() function is designed to add the item in the end of the list. `+` simply means concatenation, so you have to define there you want this concatenation to be stored.